# Creating an app with C#: hits catch(exeption) everytime

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I was trying to create a Remote Desktop Viewer. In this part of the app, this is where the user would set up their ip and port to be connected by other user. the problem is: everytime i press the connect button it would hit `catch(exception)` and failed to connect.

**Share**

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Remote_Desktop
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private readonly TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
        private NetworkStream mainStream;
        private int portNumber;

        private static Image GrabDesktop()
        {
            Rectangle bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
            Bitmap screenshot = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot);
            graphics.CopyFromScreen(bounds.X, bounds.Y, 0, 0,bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
            return screenshot;
        }

        private void SendDesktopImage()
        {
            BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            mainStream = client.GetStream();
            binaryFormatter.Serialize(mainStream, GrabDesktop());
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            portNumber = int.Parse(txtPort.Text);
            try
            {
                client.Connect(txtIp.Text, portNumber);
                MessageBox.Show("Connected!");
            }
            catch(Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Failed To Connect!");
            }
        }

        private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (btnSend.Text.StartsWith("Share"))
            {
                timer1.Start();
                btnSend.Text = "Stop Sharing";
            }
            else
            {
                timer1.Stop();
                btnSend.Text = "Share Screen";
            }
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SendDesktopImage();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help means a lot thanks! If any problem tell me i will try to fix it!

Comment: Forgotten to give a little more context or something. Updating the post soon!

Comment: you wrote the code that connects to external service in button connect click. `client.Connect(txtIp.Text, portNumber);` do you have service running on that IP an port ?

Comment: If i understand that correctly, i think the answer is no.

Comment: so `client.Connect` has to connect to some external service. Please start service that you  are connecting to and try again. You can use the `TcpServer` and host it in your application (to listen for incoming connections) and to send result of `GrabDesktop` to clients are being connected. However you have to implement some authorization protocol not to allow any client to connect.

Comment: @oleksa okay, will try. hope to reply you soon !

Comment: It would be useful to at least include the exception message in the error message box.

Comment: It seems that you don't provide the related code about TcpListener, you can provide it. Besides, I used the following code in [TcpListener Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcplistener?view=netframework-4.8). It works well. So you could try it.

Comment: @JackJJun-MSFT sorry about the late reply. Thanks will try that soon